# HTML font is larger in iPhone browser than desktop browsers

Tags: iphone, css, safari, webkit, mobile-safari

Anybody have any idea why iPhones are displaying the text highlighted in yellow with a larger font?
http://ucode.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

The text ends up being too big for the yellow highlighting background.  I've tried setting the font-size as 21px right on the `<p>` element and I've tried setting it in `em`s (1.3125em).  Looks fine on desktop browsers (including safari and chrome), but not on the iPhone....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sizing fits on my iPhone normally (about the same as my browser's appearance, Chrome).  I found this previous article as well which may help.

[Prior article StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226001/some-font-sizes-rendered-larger-on-safari-iphone)

Comment: That's exactly the article I used to fix my issue, you saw the site fixed...  I'll credit you with the answer though, thanks.