# @media not resizing fonts on iphone

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, media, font-size

I have the following CSS snippet in my site...

The span class renders fine on brower / ipad but the @media does not alter the font size on the iphone.

Please can someone let me know what I am doing wrong...

```
span.message 
{display:table-column;
width:589px; min-height: 65px;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
float:right;
vertical-align: top;
border-top-width : 0;
background : white;
font : normal 70% sans-serif; vertical-align: top; color: #000000;
border-radius : 0em 1em 1em 0em;}

@media screen and (max-width:640px){
span.message {font-size:40%;}
}
```

Thanks to gaynorvader...

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px){
   body{
   -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
   }
}
```

The above @media solves the font-resize issue. (provided you type it correctly).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226001/some-font-sizes-rendered-larger-on-safari-iphone

Comment: Thanks gaynorvader - I saw that post and I am doing as it suggests, however i still seem to have the old font size...

Comment: gaynorvader is completely correct - I have made a mistake in editing. CSS appended above.

Comment: gaynorvader - can you add the link as an answer to I can accept and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You should see the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226001/some-font-sizes-rendered-larger-on-safari-iphone) link you are missing `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;`