# Safari: incorrect viewport calculation for font sizes

Tags: ios, css, webkit, mobile-safari, viewport

1. Open the following HTML in Safari on any iPhone:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width
                                   initial-scale=1.0
                                   user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body>

<div>Responsive design</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The things are rendered correctly: we have the same font size in portrait mode (viewport width = 320px for iPhone 5) and landscape mode (viewport width = 568px for iPhone 5).

[image: Correct rendering]

2. Replace the text `Responsive design` with something like `Responsive <!-- really? --> design` (or some other tags, or add another simple div). See the difference???

[image]

It's rendered as if the viewport was 320px!

It's the most simple example. In some more complicated cases, I created several divs with correct font size on one page, but other divs' font was still incorrect.

No matter what the font is. You can use e.g. `div { font: 20px Helvetica; }`

Tested on:

- the latest iOS 9.2.1 (device) — Safari, Chrome and other Safari-based browsers
- iOS 7.1 / 8.4 / 9.2 simulators — Safari

The same issue... Is it a bug? or a feature? Why it's present there for years?

There's no such problem on iPad.

Comment: I think your meta tag has syntax error, try this and recheck: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: That's what I started with :) some validators didn't like commas, so I removed them (and tried zillions of `viewport` meta tags since then). I've just checked once again your version, the same problem.

Comment: have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3428477/877671

Comment: Oh, really!!! Consider making it the answer! Thanks so much! (I investigated a bit, this one makes sense, too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21586341/1289683 if you want to make it user-scalable. Also and I can't see a reason to use media-query, just 100% for all).

Comment: Well, I can't take credit for it :p the question is most likely a dupe, however, the interesting thing is that Safari would count comments into the string calculation when it is expected to be ignored, I'd suggest filing a report to the official Safari trac! anyway, glad I could help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some font-size's rendered larger on Safari (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226001/some-font-sizes-rendered-larger-on-safari-iphone)