# Ipad and options font size in select

Tags: css, ipad

I have a select box with one option with longer text. And on iPad it looks like that each option has a different font size. Have anybody meet with this problem?

[`Js fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/w3rzand9/)

[image]

Comment: please post the snippet here so we can see the code and test something ;)

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? -webkit-text-size-adjust is not related to this issue

Answer (score 0):

Similar question: [Some font-size's rendered larger on Safari (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3226001/3177302)

```
html {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* Prevent font scaling in landscape while allowing user zoom */
}
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2711132/3177302

Ref: https://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/controlling_text_size_in_safari_for_ios_without_disabling_user_zoom/

Comment: Unfortunately these questions have nothing common with author's question. It's not about zooming and browser rendering but about iOS options rendering

Answer (score -1):

select the class in your css and change its **font-size** , if this doesnt work, use a media query and then change its font-size