# The font-size property on iphone "landscape" seems larger?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, media-queries, font-size

I don't understand why the font-size property on iPhone "landscape" seems larger than portrait or desktop browser...

I have for `body`

```
font-size: 100%
```

and for text inside image `17px`

**PORTRAIT**
[image]

**LANDSCAPE**
[image]

I assure that in **landscape** version text seems larger.

Comment: Please, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226001/some-font-sizes-rendered-larger-on-safari-iphone

Comment: @TarasGordienko do you think is better to add the css media queries or only the property in body ?

Comment: Probably better use the media queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include this to your site:

```
body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```