# pre-formatted text not showing up properly on iPhone

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems get pre-formatted text to render properly on my iPhone.

If I just do a single pre-formatted item, things look OK (code immediately below).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Problem with <pre></title>
</head>

<style>
pre {
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  color: rgb(200,200,200);
}
</style>

<body>
<!-- exactly 80 characters -->
<div style="width:80ch"><pre>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</pre></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[From my iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50jof.png)

But when I try to do the same thing within an ordered list (code immediately below).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Problem with <pre></title>
</head>

<style>
pre {
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  color: rgb(200,200,200);
}
</style>

<body>
<div style="width:80ch"><pre>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</pre></div>
<ol>
  <li> <div style="width:80ch"><pre>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</pre></div>
</ol>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything looks fine when loading this from my computer, but on my iPhone, not only is the indented one messed up, now the original one looks wrong too.  It's almost like the font size changed when I added the list.

[from my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KehcK.png)

Links to both versions:

[first one](https://ymnh.vineyard.haus/overflow/width-question.html)

[second one](https://ymnh.vineyard.haus/overflow/width-question2.html)

How can I make this work correctly on my phone?  I need the width to be 80 characters wide so I can show standard terminal output.

Comment: Try setting the div and li to inline-block and setting the x-overflow property to scroll. Preformatted text doesn't wrap, I don't think.

Comment: That provides a work-around (thanks for that!), but the question still remains unresolved.  Note that the first one DOES display correctly on iPhone.

Comment: I see that I have received at least one downvote, but no suggestion on how to improve the question.  I'd ask anyone with feedback to please let me know how to ask a better question.

Comment: The downvote wasn't me, but from what I've observed: SO prefers inline images and code. I guess that way it persists for the life of the question, rather than counting on imgur to continue hosting the image.

Comment: Bummer.  As a new user, I am not allowed to put images in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The css unit `ch` is actually the width of a `0` (zero). So in order for your code to work you must make sure that the parent element is using a monospace font and that it's websafe so that your phone uses that monospace font.

In your case the `div` and `li` are using the `ch` units so the `div` and `li` need to have monospace fonts because they won't inherit from the child `pre` tag. You'll also need to set a matching font size between the `pre` elements and their parents.

Comment: After hours of slamming my head against the wall and feeling like the stupidest person in the world, it seems like David Kaneda's answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226001/some-font-sizes-rendered-larger-on-safari-iphone
applies to my situation (incorporating his suggestion fixed the problem instantly).

Comment: Ah, that's awesome!